# Custom Color Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on an app for kids where they press buttons and the background color changes. I have programmed the app for iOS 10 using Xcode 8.2. Unfortunately I can't find a way to set my own custom colors for the backgrounds and I am stuck with the presets... Can anybody help?

Comment: Xcode 8.2? Xcode 8.0 is still in beta.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set the background color of a view using:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1.00)
```

In Swift 3, you can use default colors like this: `UIColor.blue()`. If you want to customize your color, you can use UIColor with specific red, green, and blue values (or any other number of parameters). You convert a color from HEX to UIColor by using any number of available online tools (like: http://uicolor.xyz/#/hex-to-ui). You can also write a Swift extension to do this in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm trying to use 
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1.00)
but I get an error "expected declaration"

Comment: Where are you using this code? You want to put this code inside viewDidLoad() or some relevant method (like an IBAction for buttons).

Comment: Also, colors are fractions. So you could do 1.00 or you could do 255/255. Where 255 is the the base denominator for each rgb value. So you could have a red: 12/255, green: 120/255, blue: 168/255. I can't make this look like code as I am doing this on a phone.

Comment: @impression7vx Yup, exactly. And the nice thing about UIColor is that it takes quite a few types of parameters. So if RGB isn't what you want, you can set color however you like. And extensions make UIColor even more powerful! Although, I'm suspecting the error you're getting is because you're trying to change the background color of the view outside of a method. Try putting that line of code inside viewDidLoad()

Comment: It's not my error :P was just commenting hahaha. Trying to help out haha. But yes, the color needs to be changed inside viewDidLoad or a method from a child method called from somewhere in the heirarchy of viewDidLoad()

Comment: @impression7vx Yeah, I know haha. Got caught up putting two thoughts in one comment.

Comment: Haha all good man!

Answer (score 14):

If you have a custom color that isn't "blue", "red", etc, you can use the UIColor's RGB function. R G and B are out of 255

```
UIColor(red: 120/255.0, green: 150/255.0, blue: 200/255.0, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: 120/255 is 0 in Swift; 120.0 / 255 = 0.470588235294118

Comment: That is very true! Good catch - I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW17

There are 6 different initializers for a UIColor object, so no matter how you want to make your color, its got you covered.